# ArrayList’s remove(object) giving IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I haven’t been able to find anything that’s been helpful. Basically, when I add a bunch of characters to an ArrayList, and then try removing one of the characters, I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException, and I don’t understand why. Here's sort of a general example of what I am talking about.

```
public void addChars(){
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>();
    word = "hello";
    chars.add(word.charAt(0));
    chars.add(word.charAt(1));
    chars.add(word.charAt(2));
    chars.add(word.charAt(3));
    chars.add(word.charAt(4));

    chars.remove(word.charAt(1));
}
```

which gives the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 101, Size: 5
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:492)
at trial.addChars(trial.java:26)
at trial.main(trial.java:31)
```

I don't understand how I can be getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I'm trying to remove a character, shouldn't java look through my ArrayList "chars", and either remove or not remove depending on if the character is present?

If I alter this code to remove a character that is not present in my ArrayList it works fine, it is only when I try removing a character that is in the ArrayList that things break down.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like `char` is been treated as `int`, which would make `e` `101`...maybe try `chars.remove((Character)word.charAt(1));` instead...

Comment: which version is that? java's type system really sucks...

Answer (score 1):

```
chars.remove((Character)word.charAt(1));
```

The ArrayList.remove() method can also take an integer index. Try:

```
chars.remove(chars.indexOf(word.charAt(1)));
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Then what's [`ArrayList#remove(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove(java.lang.Object))?  I must have been doing it wrong all these years :P

Comment: remove() is interpreting the argument as an integer not an object

Comment: Hence the cast to a character in the first excerpt of code